# Developer-safe bi-directional relationships with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I know how to map bi-directional relationships with NHibernate, but does anyone know an effective technique to make them 'developer safe'.

What I mean by that, is that as soon as one end of the relationship is established, the other end should also be set, for example:

```
[Test]
public void TestBidirectionalRelationships_WhenAddingOptionToProduct()
{
    var product = new Product();

    var productOption = new ProductOption();

    product.AddOption(productOption);

    Assert.That(product.Options.Contains(productOption));
    Assert.That(productOption.Product, Is.EqualTo(product);
}

[Test]
public void TestBidirectionalRelationships_WhenSettingProductOnOption()
{
    /* Alternatively, productOption.Product would have no public setter */

    var product = new Product();

    var productOption = new ProductOption();

    productOption.Product = product;

    Assert.That(product.Options.Contains(productOption));
    Assert.That(productOption.Product, Is.EqualTo(product);
}
```

How would one achieve this, without making the code horrendously complex, and whilst also keeping NHibernate happy?

Comment: That depends on what you mean with "horrendously complex"

Answer (score 4):

One side:

```
class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        _Options = new List<ProductOption>();
    }

    ICollection<ProductOption> _Options;
    public virtual IEnumerable<ProductOption> ProductOptions
    {
        get { return _Options.Select(x => x); }
    }

    public virtual AddOption(ProductOption option)
    {
        option.Product = this;
    }

    protected internal virtual AddOptionInternal(ProductOption option)
    {
        _Options.Add(option);
    }
}
```

Many side:

```
class ProductOption
{
    Product _Product;
    public virtual Product Product
    {
        get { return _Product; }
        set
        {
            _Product = value;
            _Product.AddOptionInternal(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="Product">
    ...
    <bag name="Options" access="field.pascalcase-underscore">
    ...
<class name="ProductOption">
    ...
    <many-to-one name="Product" access="field.pascalcase-underscore"/>
```

Removal of options from the collection (from either side) is left as an exercise :-)

Answer (score 2):

Diego's solution is fine but I prefer this pattern:

One side:

```
public class Product
{

    private IList<ProductOption> _options; 

    public Product()
    {
        _options = new List<ProductOption>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ProductOption> ProductOptions
    {
        get { return _options; }
    }

    public virtual AddOption(ProductOption option)
    {
        // equality must be overridden for this to work
        // Check contains to break out of endless loop
        if (!_options.Contains(options))
        { 
            _options.Add(option);
            option.Product = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Many side:

```
public class ProductOption
{
    Product _product;

    public virtual Product Product
    {
        get { return _product; }
        set
        {
            _product = value;
            _product.AddOption(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's less coupled... however, I'm certainly not in love with that Contains call ;-)

Comment: @Diego - Could you explain why? Curious as to why because I sometimes do similar.

Comment: @Phill because it has a cost, which can be low if it's an already-loaded or in-memory small collection, moderate if it's big, and high if it forces loading a bag from the DB.

Comment: Ahh, ok, the relationships I deal with are usually relatively small (0-10 items), and almost always pre-loaded.

Comment: @Diego -- your answer loads the collection also, doesn't it? The collection has to be loaded to keep both sides in sync. In some cases I check NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized (I think I have that right) to cancel the Add if the collection has not been loaded. Of course this relies on NHibernate being smart enough to flush the object before loading the collection.

Comment: @Jamie calling Add on a Bag does not cause loading (because it always succeeds, unlike a Set)

Comment: This solution is fine if it performs well (which it usually would). One more thing though - this code relies on single references to the distinct ProductOption objects, so that the Contains method can simply do a reference equality check. I believe NHibernate will ensure that this is the case, as long as we are not trying to work across Sessions. It is non-trivial though if we have to work around the possibility of the same ProductOption being stored with two different references.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/03/10/strengthening-your-domain-encapsulated-collections.aspx) which specifically addresses this issue. The guidance here is very valuable for keeping such relationships clean by encapsulating the collection operations within your domain model.